# Как удалить ненужный символ в строке

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Вопрос такой. Нужно, чтобы функция отображала любые введенные значения как строку, в которой все слова разделены пробелом, первая буква заглавная,а в конце стоит точка. Здесь же точка отображается через пробел, что логично. Как мне лучше поставить точку в конце строки, чтобы перед ней не было пробела?
Буду очень благодарна.

```
function getTheSentence(words){
  words[words.length] = ".";
   return words
   .map(
   (word, index) => index == 0 ? word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) : word
   )
   .join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы точку дописывайте к последнему слову, например, сразу:

```
words[words.length-1] += ".";
```

Или к результирующей строке, а не в массив:

```
.join(' ') + '.';
```

Comment: Второй вариант предпочтительнее, конечно.

Comment: Да, лучше второй вариант

Comment: все гениальное просто. Спасибо огромное!